# How to set thread priority in privately managed pools in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, threadpool

I am following the examples given [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/harip/archive/2010/10/11/introduction-to-the-windows-threadpool-part-1.aspx). While I am able to successfully create threads, these threads have default affinity to all the processes.

How do I set affinity? Can someone please provide an example on how can I use SetThreadAffinityMask with the examples given on above link?

Comment: So do you want affinity or priority?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'm going to assume you want affinity. The second parameter of `SetThreadAffinityMask` is a bit mask representing on which processors the thread is allowed to run. The bits are set to 1 on the corresponding processors. For example:

```
// binary 01, so it allows this thread to run on CPU 0
SetThreadAffinityMask(hThread, 0x01); 
// binary 10, so it allows this thread to run on CPU 1
SetThreadAffinityMask(hThread, 0x02); 
// binary 11, so it allows this thread to run on CPU 0 or CPU 1
SetThreadAffinityMask(hThread, 0x03);
```